# neo4j traversal example it didn't give the right node number

Tags: neo4j

0i want to traversal using neo4j.
while it give me the output from newno[1](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorial-traversal-java-api.html) like

```
(4354)
(4354)--[KNOWS,8335]-->(4358)
(4354)--[KNOWS,8335]-->(4358)--[KNOWS,8332]-->(4357)
(4354)--[KNOWS,8334]-->(4356)
```

why it didn't give me right node number from 0-4? and depth is from 1-3
thanks.
i just want to traversal in this graph like level by level and output the backward and forward separately.

The expected output should be like:

```
(1)
(1)--[KNOWS,0]-->(2)
(1)--[KNOWS,0]-->(2)--[KNOWS,2]-->(2)
(1)--[KNOWS,0]-->(4)
```

the number after KNOWS should also like smaller number. like [neo4j example](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorial-traversal-java-api.html)
the java code is :

```
public class TraversalExample
{
    private GraphDatabaseService db;
    private TraversalDescription friendsTraversal;

    public TraversalExample( GraphDatabaseService db )
    {
        this.db = db;
        // START SNIPPET: basetraverser
        friendsTraversal = db.traversalDescription()
                .depthFirst()
                .relationships( Rels.KNOWS )
                .uniqueness( Uniqueness.RELATIONSHIP_GLOBAL );
        // END SNIPPET: basetraverser
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        final String DB_PATH = "target/neo4j-hello-db";
        GraphDatabaseService db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
        TraversalExample op = new TraversalExample( db );
        op.createTheGraph();
        op.shutdownGraph();
    }
    public void shutdownGraph()
    {
        try
        {
            if ( db != null )
            {
                db.shutdown();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            db = null;
        }
    }

    public Node createTheGraph()
    {
        try ( Transaction tx = db.beginTx() )
        {
            // START SNIPPET: createGraph

            Node[] newno=new Node[5];
            for(int i=0; i<newno.length; i++){
                newno[i]=db.createNode();
            }

            newno[1].createRelationshipTo(newno[2], Rels.KNOWS );
            newno[1].createRelationshipTo(newno[4], Rels.KNOWS );
            newno[4].createRelationshipTo(newno[2], Rels.KNOWS );
            newno[2].createRelationshipTo(newno[3], Rels.KNOWS );
            System.out.println(knowsTraverserforward(newno[1]));

            return newno[1];
        }
    }
    public String knowsLikesTraverser( Node node )
    {
        String output = "";
        // START SNIPPET: knowslikestraverser
        for ( Path position : db.traversalDescription()
                .depthFirst()
                .relationships( Rels.KNOWS )
                .relationships( Rels.LIKES, Direction.INCOMING )
                .evaluator( Evaluators.toDepth( 5 ) )
                .traverse( node ) )
        {
            output += position + "\n";
        }
        // END SNIPPET: knowslikestraverser
        return output;
    }
    public String knowsTraverserforward( Node node )
    {
        String output = "";
        // START SNIPPET: knowslikestraverser
        for ( Path position : db.traversalDescription()
                .depthFirst()
                .relationships( Rels.KNOWS, Direction.OUTGOING )
                .evaluator( Evaluators.toDepth(5 ) )
                .traverse( node ) )
        {
            output += position + "\n";
        }
        // END SNIPPET: knowslikestraverser
        return output;
    }


    public String traverseBaseTraverser( Node node )
    {
        String output = "";
        // START SNIPPET: traversebasetraverser
        for ( Path path : friendsTraversal.traverse( node ) )
        {
            output += path + "\n";
        }
        // END SNIPPET: traversebasetraverser
        return output;
    }

    public String depth3( Node node )
    {
        String output = "";
        // START SNIPPET: depth3
        for ( Path path : friendsTraversal
                .evaluator( Evaluators.toDepth( 3 ) )
                .traverse( node ) )
        {
            output += path + "\n";
        }
        // END SNIPPET: depth3
        return output;
    }

    public String depth4( Node node )
    {
        String output = "";
        // START SNIPPET: depth4
        for ( Path path : friendsTraversal
                .evaluator( Evaluators.fromDepth( 2 ) )
                .evaluator( Evaluators.toDepth( 4 ) )
                .traverse( node ) )
        {
            output += path + "\n";
        }
        // END SNIPPET: depth4
        return output;
    }

    public String nodes( Node node )
    {
        String output = "";
        // START SNIPPET: nodes
        for ( Node currentNode : friendsTraversal
                .traverse( node )
                .nodes() )
        {
            output += currentNode.getProperty( "name" ) + "\n";
        }
        // END SNIPPET: nodes
        return output;
    }

    public String relationships( Node node )
    {
        String output = "";
        // START SNIPPET: relationships
        for ( Relationship relationship : friendsTraversal
                .traverse( node )
                .relationships() )
        {
            output += relationship.getType().name() + "\n";
        }
        // END SNIPPET: relationships
        return output;
    }

    // START SNIPPET: sourceRels
    private enum Rels implements RelationshipType
    {
        LIKES, KNOWS
    }
    // END SNIPPET: sourceRels


}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what your current result is and what the expected result is?

Answer (score 1):

The internal node id of any node is a implementation detail. You should not take any assumptions on the node id.

I guess if you print the node id of the nodes being created they would pretty much with your traversal:

```
for(int i=0; i<newno.length; i++){
    newno[i]=db.createNode();
    System.out.println(newno[i].getId());
}
```

Comment: hi you solution did not solve the problem hi, i just want to make the print id of the node is the same as i such as from 0 to newno.length. like 0, 1, 2,3, 4, .....i just your code. it give me the large node id like 503047 503046 503045 503044 503043 503042 503041 503040 503055how to fix this problem